# How to check datetime if it falls between a range? YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, timestamp

**GIVEN:**

```
start range: 2016-01-01 21:00:00
end range: 2016-02-29 23:59:59

inputed time: 2016-02-03 01:00:00
```

I cannot find any code that checks YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format at once.
I only find codes for checking either the date or time.

so I just combined both and did something like this.

**pseudo code:**

```
if(checkdate()== true)
{
   if(checktime()== true)
   {
     alert('yes');
   }
   else
   {
     alert('no');
   }

}
else
{
   alert('no');
}
```

I just realized that doesn't work after all because based on my Given example.

It would fall true for checkdate() but be false for checktime() since 01:00:00 does not fall between 21:00:00-23:59:59 but it should have been true because the start and end ranges are different days.

How do i do this?

Comment: really simple if you provide valid ISO date string and compare `Date` objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function `checkdate` that parses the dates and compares

```
function checkdate(_input, _start, _end) {
    function parseDate(x) {
        if (typeof x === 'string') {
            var parts = x.split(/[-: ]/g).map(Number);
            x = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
        }
        return x;
    }

    _input = parseDate(_input);
    _start = parseDate(_start);
    _end   = parseDate(_end);

    return _input > _start && _input < _end;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4bzLd8qc/)

---

For fun only, here's a golfed version

```
function checkdate() {
    var y = [].slice.call(arguments).map(function(x) {
        var arr = [null].concat(x.split(/[-: ]/g).map(Number)); arr[2]--;
        return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, arr));
    });
    return y[0] > y[1] && y[0] < y[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var startRange = (new Date("2016-01-01 21:00:00".replace(/-/g, '/')).getTime()),
    endRange = (new Date("2016-02-29 23:59:59".replace(/-/g, '/')).getTime()),
    input = (new Date("2016-02-03 01:00:00".replace(/-/g, '/')).getTime());

if(input >= startRage && input <= endRange) {}
```

Comment: not valid date strings... format is not supported cross browser. Try that in firefox for example will all be `invalid date` returned

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, in case of question startRange / endRange `replace(/-/g, '/')`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Date objects directly. Convert your strings to correctly formatted date strings if needed.

```
var beginRange = new Date(".....");
var endRange = new Date(".....");

var myDate = new Date(".....");

if (myDate > beginRange && myDate < endRange)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working solution. You need to replace "-" with "/" then convert to Date

```
var startDate = new Date("2016-01-01 21:00:00".replace(/-/g, '/'));
var endDate = new Date("2016-02-29 23:59:59".replace(/-/g, '/'));

var input = new Date("2016-02-03 01:00:00".replace(/-/g, '/'));

if(input <= endDate && input >= startDate) {
        alert("success");
    }
        else  {
            alert("Failure");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regex:

```
var date = "2016-01-01 21:00:00";
var pattern = /\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/;
var correct_match = date.match(pattern);

if (correct_match) {
  alert('yes');
}
else {
  alert('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a sensible datetime format, you can just use string comparison:

```
$ node
> rangeStart="2016-01-01 21:00:00"
'2016-01-01 21:00:00'
> rangeEnd="2016-02-29 23:59:59"
'2016-02-29 23:59:59'
> inputDate="2016-02-03 01:00:00"
'2016-02-03 01:00:00'
> if (rangeStart <= inputDate && inputDate <= rangeEnd) console.log("input date is in range")
input date is in range
```

You just need to validate that the input is in the right format.